# php for loop for creating objects doesnt work

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, iteration

i have this code

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($testas); $x += 2) {

    $object = new stdClass();
    $object->$testas[0] = $x;
    $newArr[] = $object;
    }

echo json_encode($newArr);
```

everything works well here, but if i chagne $testas array like this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($testas); $x += 2) {

    $object = new stdClass();
    $object->$testas[$x] = $x;
    $newArr[] = $object;
    }

echo json_encode($newArr);
```

it doesnt print out anything. Please help

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It's not usual for loop.

Comment: i have an array say like this: $array = array ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'); And i want it to print a json that it would be like this: [{"a":"d"},{"c":"d"}

Comment: What does it mean: `$x += 2`?

Comment: Why `count($testas)` (just variable) but `$object->$testas[$x]` (object property). Are that the same array or not?

Comment: i have an array say like this: $array = array ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'); And i want it to print a json that it would be like this: [{"a":"d"},{"c":"d"}

Comment: $x +=2 means it adds 2 instead of one ($x++)

Comment: the final line should be like this: $object->$testas[$x] = testas[$x+1]; but i just want to show the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that you want. Odd elements become properties, event elements become values of the key-value objects. And that objects are in one array.

It's better for me to wrap variable object field name in curly braces. Just not to be messed up with that.

```
$testas = array ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$newArr = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < count($testas); $x += 2) {

     $object = new stdClass();
     $object->{$testas[$x]} = $testas[$x + 1];

     $newArr[] = $object;
}

echo json_encode($newArr);
```

Output is:

> [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]

Comment: i dont know what you did here because i had the same code but i works, thanks

Comment: May be your other code is not the same as mine. You provided just part of your code. Check other code carefully.